# ¿Cómo detectar en una página web cuando el usuario aprieta el botón "ir atrás" del navegador?

Tags: javascript

Necesito detectar en una página web cuando el usuario hizo "clic" en el botón regresar del navegador, en la documentación que he buscado sugieren que use el evento en el body de "onbeforeunload=algunaAccionOFuncion()" pero la verdad es que eso no funciona, para evidencia tengo el sitio web siguiente o link que lleva a una página que tiene esa función en el body:

[este es el enlace de evidencia y demostración](https://ventas.countier.com.mx/pruebaregreso.php)

para dejar más claro puse esto en el body

```
 <body onbeforeunload="alert('se abandona pagina')">
```

Pero no funciona.... :(

¿Alguna orientación?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload

Answer (score -1):

Intenté realizarlo directamente por medio de un eventListener y funcionó, el comportamiento de un beforeunload siempre ha sido muy contradictorio, pero el mensaje final depende del soporte del navegador que utilice el usuario.

Ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log('Esto se ejecuta antes de salir de la página');
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: no funciona en chrome por que el alert el navegador lo bloquea